# CORS problem with B2C and Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, cors, azure-ad-b2c

I have enabled CORS in my ASP.NET/Angular application by using AddCors and EnableCors in controllers. My application is communicating with AD B2C pages. After build I have this error in the console :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XXX.b2clogin.com/ (redirected
>   from 'https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/User/Info') from origin
>   'https://XXX.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Startup.cs :

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

Controller :

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[Authorize]
public class UserEditController : Controller
```

I have enabled CORS on Azure too by putting : `Allowed Origins - *` .

UPDATE:

```
[Route("User/Info")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoggedInUserInfo()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var viewmodel = await userService.GetUserByObjectId(user);
        return Json(new { loggedIn = "true", user = viewmodel });
    }
    return Json(new { loggedIn = "false" });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Memo Are you attempting a cross-origin request to the `.b2clogin.com` origin from your own page?

Comment: Yes that’s it. I have enable CORS on my B2C pages too.

Comment: What is the scenario for which https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/User/Info is attempting to make a XMLHttpRequest to b2clogin.com?

Comment: @OmerIqbal I have updated the post. You can see the scenario, the method is querying Azure AD to get the user with object Id.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you're attempting a cross-origin request from the **https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/** domain to the **https://xxx.b2clogin.com/** domain.

Currently the `.b2clogin.com` domain doesn't allow any cross-origin requests from any other domain.