# How can I send a web request to the b2clogin domain from my own custom domain?

Tags: azure, cors, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to make a web request to an Azure App Service (**Azure Function**) which is secured with Azure Active Directory Authentication (B2C Application Registration details used). The web request is being made from a web application (**Portal**) via simple JavaScript calls (I do not have access to the portals source code.

The web application (**Portal**) and Azure App Service (**Azure Function**) are secured using Azure B2C and require users to login with their Azure AD B2C accounts. This is working fine.

Requests made to the Azure Function from the Portal surface the following error in the browser console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XXX.b2clogin.com/XXX.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...' (redirected from 'https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/api/MyMethod') from origin 'https://ZZZ.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The same web request made made in a new browser tab successfully shows the secured resource (assuming an active B2C session exists in the browser).

I have spent a significant amount of time reading through the [Azure B2C documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564978), making multiple requests for tokens etc, all to no resolve.

I believe the harsh truth of the matter is outlined in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564978), but how can this be architected differently to circumvent this pitfall?

> Currently the .b2clogin.com domain doesn't allow any cross-origin requests from any other domain.

While this appears true based on the CORS issues being surfaced here, how can I send a web request from my **Portal** domain (XXX.com), to my **Azure Function** (YYY.azurewebsites.net), which are both secured using my B2C tenant/application registration.

EDIT: I am aware (based on the error I am receiving above) that the **Azure Function** is redirecting to the to the B2C login page when the initial call is made form the **Portal** to the **Azure Function**.

I am including my current setup below - previously I have only secured App Services using Azure AD authentication and access by obtaining bearer tokens. Not possible in this scenario as I do not have access to the **Portal** code for secure storage of private keys/secrets - I am dependent on the SSO experience - calls must be made in JavaScript.

**App Service - Authentication (Azure Function)**

- Log in with Azure Active Directory
- Client ID: *Azure AD B2C application registraion ID*
- Issuer Url: *Taken from my Signin/Signup user flow*

**Azure AD B2C Tenant - App Registration**

- Include web app / web API: Yes
- Allow implicit flow: Yes

**Client side code calling Azure Function**

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "https://YYY.azurewebsites.net/api/MyMethod",
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
      },
    });
```

Some guidance on this would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: If something is unclear or incorrect in my question, I believe it would be more beneficial for all if the person(s) who downvoted it to comment and make the issues known so they can be resolved.

Comment: Since both are protected by B2C, did you send the access token from the Portal to the Function in the authorization header? That would prevent the function from returning a 302 to b2clogin.com.

Comment: @JasSuri, I was not passing any bearer tokens in the Authorization header (I wrongly assumed my SSO session would magically take care of/recognize my session). I added a Authorization header to my request to the Function and can confirm the redirect is gone, the CORS issue along with it. I have been able to successfully retrieve an access token using MSAL in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp) locally. Ultimately, the issue was I need to acquire an access token to access the Function, silently or via a prompt. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my scenario was to make use of [single sign-on with MSAL.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso) using [impicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/implicit-flow-single-page-application) (which is taken care of by the MSAL).

Specifically, [SSO without MSAL.js login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#sso-without-msaljs-login), whereby I do not have to log in again to access the **Azure Function**, as the user would have already been logged in via the **Portal** and have an active Azure AD B2C session.

Instead, I call the `acquireTokenSilent` method, passing in the required parameters to obtain a Bearer access token that can be used to access my secured **Azure Function**.

A working example of this scenario (SPA calling an Azure App Service), can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp) in Microsofts GitHub repo. My setup was complete in so far as I only had to configure the sample with my tenant/app specific details.